# Int to non optional string

Tags: swift

I have a string `00012`. I need to make a string `12` out of it. And load then UIImage by concatenating strings into name.
So I do the following

```
let myString = "00012"
let myInt = Int(myString)
let imageName = "name_\(myInt)"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

The problem is that (myInt) return an optional. I don't get `imageName = name_12`, I get `imageName = name_optional(12)`

How can I get rid of optional ?

I can't trim first 3 zeros from initial string, because number can be 00001

Comment: Optionals are a completely integral part of the Swift programming language. They're covered in great detail and clarity in [the first section, "The Basics", of the Swift Programming Language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330). Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use optional bindings:

```
let myString = "00012"
if let myInt = Int(myString) {
  let imageName = "name_\(myInt)"
  let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```

alternatively use regular expression:

```
let myString = "00012"
let myStringWithoutLeadingZeros = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "^0+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
let imageName = "name_" + myStringWithoutLeadingZeros
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unwrap the value directly

```
let myString = "00012"
let myInt = Int(myString)! // unwrapping 
let imageName = "name_\(myInt)"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

Or you can use optional binding

```
let myString = "00012"
if let myInt = Int(myString) { // Optional binding
    let imageName = "name_\(myInt)"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```